# Docker Command and ECS with multi-line Inputs

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs

I have my command defined as the following within my **ECS Task Definition**:

```
compact,--wait,--http-address=0.0.0.0:10912,--objstore.config=<YAML FILE>
```

However, I'm unable to find a way to pass a YAML file to this command position. In addition within the YAML file, I also need to add some sensitive data in via environment variables (access/secret key, shown below)

Below is an example of the YAML file:

```
type: S3
config:
  bucket: mybucket
  access_key: <access_key>
  secret_key: <secret_key>
  endpoint: s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
  insecure: true
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks...

Comment: Are you using any kind of IaC tool? Terraform has a good way of providing this kind of information for ECS tasks.

Comment: Yep using TF, any pointers? Not found anything useful in the provider docs yet...

Comment: We're using `templatefile` function to render the template written in `.tpl` format. Then, using `data template_file` we map between values we want to pass to the task definition and the values provided.

Comment: ok this sounds like it could work. Any chance you could put some examples in here to help myself and others...?

Answer (score 1):

My approach is to override the entrypoint of the image. I replace the entrypoint with non-secret environment variable exports and a `run.sh` (everything base64 encoded without newlines) that decodes everything and calls the former command that was the entrypoint.

For secret data I use `secrets` instead of environment variables.

Here is an example from production. I use Terraform, but the idea is the same.

Entrypoint:

```
entryPoint: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", join(" ", [
        "export DOMAIN='domain.com';",
        "export VICTORIA_YML=${base64encode(file("${path.module}/files/promstack/victoria/victoria.yml"))};",
        "echo '${base64encode(file("${path.module}/files/promstack/victoria/run.sh"))}' | base64 -d | sh;"
      ])],
```

run.sh:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

set -x

require () {
    if [ ! "$1" ]; then 
        echo "ERROR: var not found"
        exit 1 
    fi 
}

expand () {
    var_name="${1}"
    file="${2}"

    eval var="\$$var_name"

    sed -i "s+\${${var_name}}+${var}+g" ${file}
    sed -i "s+\$${var_name}+${var}+g" ${file}
}

# ==============================================================================

require ${DOMAIN}
require ${VICTORIA_YML}

echo ${VICTORIA_YML} | base64 -d > /tmp/victoria.yml
chmod 666 /tmp/victoria.yml

expand DOMAIN /tmp/victoria.yml

arguments="\
--storageDataPath=/storage \
--loggerFormat=json \
--promscrape.config=/tmp/victoria.yml \
--promscrape.config.strictParse \
--promscrape.fileSDCheckInterval=15s \
"

/bin/sh -c "/victoria-metrics-prod ${arguments}"
```

Comment: Using join(" ; ", [ "<command1>", "<command2>" ]) solved the issues I was facing, thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, I think something can be done by using `data template_file` with an ECS task definition inside the template file. An example of ECS task template file:

```
[
  {
    "name": "${service_name}",
    "image": "${service_image}",
    "essential": true,
    "portMappings": [
      {
        "containerPort": ${service_port}
      }
    ],
    "secrets": [
      ${service_secrets}
    ],
    "dockerLabels": {
      "traefik.port" : "${service_port}",
      "traefik.enable" : "true",
      "traefik.frontend.rule": "Host:${service_hosts}",
      "traefik.frontend.passHostHeader": "true",
      "traefik.frontend.headers.SSLRedirect": "true",
      "traefik.frontend.headers.SSLProxyHeaders": "X-Forwarded-Proto: https"
    },
    "logConfiguration": {
      "logDriver": "awslogs",
      "options": {
        "awslogs-group": "${service_awslogs}",
        "awslogs-region": "${cluster_region}",
        "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Every variable starting with `${service_*}` will be populated by using the following:

```
data "template_file" "app-task-definition" {
  template = file("task-definitions/app.json.tpl")

  vars = {
    cluster_region = var.cluster_region

    service_name    = var.application.name
    service_port    = var.application.port
    service_image   = var.app_image
    service_hosts   = join(", ", var.app_traefik_hosts)
    service_cluster = var.cluster_name
    service_secrets = join(", ", module.app-secrets.rendered)
    service_awslogs = var.aws_ssm_prefix
  }
}
```

I think you could also define a location for YML file you want to pass as a part of the task definition. Last, but not the least, you would then use the data resource as input for container definitions:

```
container_definitions = data.template_file.app-task-definition.rendered
```

For passing secrets, there's a custom module defined, which is used later to pass and store values in SSM:

```
variable "aws_ssm_parameter_list" {
  type = list
}

variable "service_prefix" {
  type = string
}

data "template_file" "service_secrets" {
  count = length(var.aws_ssm_parameter_list)

  template = <<EOF
    {
        "name": "$${secret_name}",
        "valueFrom": "$${secret_path}"
    }
EOF

  vars = {
    secret_name = var.aws_ssm_parameter_list[count.index].name
    secret_path = "${var.service_prefix}/${var.aws_ssm_parameter_list[count.index].name}"
  }
}

output "rendered" {
  value = data.template_file.service_secrets.*.rendered
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this solution doesnt work when you try to put a template (i.e for the YAML) inside of the task definition.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, I never really tried to pass YAML files using this method. But that's something to consider for me and improve the code.